# How to recover photos from NQ Vault?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, nqvault

NQ Vault itself suddenly vanished all of my data photos. How can I recover all of my photos back, those are very important to me. I am using Intex Aqua 4+ and I have same Vault password, same phone, same memory card.

Please help me.

Comment: Try installing a file browser like Cabinet and browsing for your pics.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your External Storage.
check the hidden files shown.
there will be some folder files with .ext format.
If there is these files, then install again Vault app from Google Play Store.
Wait for some seconds, It will automatically restore it.
and if you don't find any file over hidden area then

Comment: … then … what? Something's missing at the end here.